# VBA Forms - Buttons with images

Tags: image, forms, vba, button

I'm trying to use a web-style button on my form, using some pictures (ok-off button, ok-pressed button and ok button).

I'm trying to do the same as in a website. change button color when rolling over the mouse and change color again when click.

But I'm missing something here. I have achieved to change the button imagen when mouse is over it, but when I click on it, only change the picture (by procedure `MouseMove`), but when I release mouse button, event can't go to `mouseUp` event. What am I missing?

```
Private Sub okpress_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    If okpress.Visible = True Then
        okoff.Visible = False
        okpress.Visible = True
        ok.Visible = False
    End If
    MsgBox "ha entrado", vbOKOnly, "Prueba"
End Sub

Private Sub okoff_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    If okoff.Visible = True Or okpress.Visible = True Then
        okoff.Visible = False
        okpress.Visible = False
        ok.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ok_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    If okpress.Visible = False Then
        okoff.Visible = False
        okpress.Visible = True
        ok.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    ok.Visible = False
    okpress.Visible = False
    okoff.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The MouseUP event occurs after a MouseDOWN on the same form, and not where the mouse is. And when you hide the form, you also stop the event chain.

A solution for your case would be, instead of hiding the button, just show the other one in front of it.. So the MouseUP event will still occur when you release the mouse, and the result will be the same.

--
Place the buttons/images from back to front in this order: ok(c1), off(c2), press(c3)

Code:

```
Private Sub c1_Click()
c1.Visible = False
c2.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub c1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
c3.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub c1_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
c3.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub c2_Click()
c1.Visible = True
c2.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub c2_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
c3.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub c2_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
c3.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
c1.Visible = False
c3.Visible = False
c2.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried it removing `ok.Visible = False` from the procedure and sending it to bottom on design, but still happening the same thing

Comment: I edited my answer with a code that worked for me.. havent tested it with images though. Also, why the last part of the code is disabling it when the mouse moves in the form?

Comment: It was for recovering the normal status of the buttons when loosing mouse focus